# Issue with the 'If exist' and 'else' function in batch script

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, exists

So I want to run the operation (denoted by `S1`) in subdirectories only under the condition that the subdirectory contains an `.mkv` file along with a `.ttf`/`.otf` file. This what I have done do far...

```bat
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('Dir/B/AD 2^>Nul^|FindStr/IVXC:"Revised"'
) Do If Exist "%%A\*.mkv" ( 
If Exist "%%A\*.ttf" (
        If Not Exist "Revised\" MD "Revised" 2>Nul||Exit /B
        Call :S1 "%%A")
) else ( 
If Exist "%%A\*.otf" (
        If Not Exist "Revised\" MD "Revised" 2>Nul||Exit /B
        Call :S1 "%%A"))
GoTo :EOF
```

The issue is the `S1` operation only takes place when there is a `.otf` file and not the `.ttf` file. However if I do this...

```bat
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('Dir/B/AD 2^>Nul^|FindStr/IVXC:"Revised"'
) Do If Exist "%%A\*.mkv" ( 
Do If Exist "%%A\*.ttf" (
        If Not Exist "Revised\" MD "Revised" 2>Nul||Exit /B
        Call :S1 "%%A")
) else ( 
If Exist "%%A\*.otf" (
        If Not Exist "Revised\" MD "Revised" 2>Nul||Exit /B
        Call :S1 "%%A"))
GoTo :EOF
```

By adding a `Do` right before the `If Exist` in the 3<sup>rd</sup> line, the script functions as intended but the I would keep getting this error

> 'Do' is not recognized as a internal or external command

Could I please get some help with the issue of getting the script to function as intended without the prompts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you add `do` at that place? `If Exist "%%A\*.mkv" ( Do something )` will **run a command named `do`** if the file exists, but since that command doesn't exist, the execution will fail with the above message

In a `for` loop the word `do` is a keyword which is part of the syntax, therefore you must have it before the command you want to run in each loop. Run `for /?` to get help about syntax

Besides, your description is unclear. Do you want to call S1 if

- there exists (*.mkv and *.ttf) or (*.otf), or
- there exists (*.mkv) and (*.ttf or *.otf)?

Your code is doing the former. It's hard to see because your indentation is terrible. Here's it after fixing

```bat
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('Dir/B/AD 2^>Nul^|FindStr/IVXC:"Revised"') Do (
    If Exist "%%A\*.mkv" (
        If Exist "%%A\*.ttf" (
            If Not Exist "Revised\" MD "Revised" 2>Nul||Exit /B
            Call :S1 "%%A"
        )
    ) else ( 
        If Exist "%%A\*.otf" (
            If Not Exist "Revised\" MD "Revised" 2>Nul||Exit /B
            Call :S1 "%%A"
        )
    )
)
```

But why do you use 2 contradictory options (`/V` and `/X`) in `findstr`? And people often use all lowercase or all upper case for commands/keywords, not CamelCase like that. So to check for the latter condition you can use this

```bat
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%a in ('dir /b /ad 2^>nul ^| findstr /IVXC:"Revised"') do (
    if exist "%%a\*.mkv" (
        if exist "%%a\*.ttf" (
            if not exist "Revised\" md "Revised" 2>nul || exit /b
            Call :S1 "%%a"
        )
        if exist "%%a\*.otf" (
            if not exist "Revised\" md "Revised" 2>nul || exit /b
            call :S1 "%%a"
        )
    )
)
```